# Different currencies in the same opportunity

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, currency, currencytype

it's possible to have different currencies in one opportunity? for example:

line item 1 $USD
line item 2 $MXN

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. Currently we can add products in different currencies to a price book. But when you try add some  products to an opportunity, you can add only those products with same currency as the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I guess users will need to Create different opportunities with different currencies each.